# Angular. Finding all images in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to find all img tags in a div. These img tags are in p tags that sit in the div. I made a plunkr to see if I could get it working but no joy so far. If anyone could have a look and point me in the right direction that would be great.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div >
  <p image-append>
      <p >
        <img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg" />
      </p>
    <p>
      <img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" />  
    </p>  
  </p>

</div>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('imageAppend', imageAppend);
/*@ngInject*/
function imageAppend() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            console.log("elemnts are ===== ", element.find('img'))
        }
    };
}
```

plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/W1PWVgtysZ4cOwaIpmbc?p=preview

Comment: Have you tried: `var images = $('div#give-this-div-an-id img');` ?

Comment: having some html and then parse it is not angular approach. If you have control on this template you should add directive to img tags.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I do not have the ability to attach it to the image directly. The html is returned to me and an image is not always present.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('img', imageAppend);

function imageAppend() {
           return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    console.log("elemnts are ===== ", element)
                }
            };
        }
```

Comment: I have updated the code above. Could you please try now.